# djnago waiting for server response time problem in production

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a django app that its main purpose is to make an api .

it has:

1. api/ url for api that renders data from db
2. test/ url for a test page that only returns HttpResponse("Done")
3. insert/ url for inserting data to db

the speed is ok(255 ms) in development but  it's sometimes fast (260 ms) and most of the time slow(30-40 s) in production even for loading that test page which only shows a single word.

is this problem related to the code or to the hosting provider?

note: we use react for frontend  and routes are like: mainsite.com/home and we use subdomain like: api.mainsite.com/api or api.mainsite.com/insert for backend

this is the abstract class for other tables that have these same fields and different model methods.(Equipment and Machine models are silmiar to the Device so i  bring them in codes)

```
     class Device(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
    
        gas1 = models.FloatField()
        gas2= models.FloatField()
        gas3= models.FloatField()
        gas4= models.FloatField()
        gas5= models.FloatField()
        gas6= models.FloatField()
    
        humidity = models.FloatField()
        temperature = models.FloatField()
    
        created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        display_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, db_index=True)
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Device, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        time = f"{str(self.created_datetime.date())}{(format(self.created_datetime.hour,'02d'))}:{(format(self.created_datetime.minute // 5 * 5, '02d'))}:00"
        formatt = "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"
        self.display_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, formatt)
        super(Device, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializer:
equipment and machine serializers are similar to th below so i didn't bring them

```
class Deviceserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = [
            "id",
            "name",
            "room",
            "deviceName",
            "total gas",
            "gas1",
            "gas2",
            "gas3",
            "gas4",
            "gas5",
            "gas6",
            "humidity",
            "temperature",
            "method1",
            "method2",
            "method3",
            "method4",
            "method5",
            "method6",
            "slug",
            "display_datetime",
        ]
```

view:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def getData(request):
    device_101 = device_101.objects.last()
    device_102 = device_102.objects.last()
    device_103 = device_103.objects.last()
    device_104 = device_104.objects.last()
    device_105 = device_105.objects.last()
    device_106 = device_106.objects.last()
    device_108 = device_108.objects.last()
    device_109 = device_109.objects.last()
    device_110 = device_110.objects.last()
    device_111 = device_111.objects.last()
    device_112 = device_112.objects.last()
    device_113 = device_113.objects.last()
    device_114 = device_114.objects.last()
    device_115 = device_115.objects.last()
    device_116 = device_116.objects.last()
    device_124 = device_124.objects.last()
    device_125 = device_125.objects.last()
    device_126 = device_126.objects.last()
    device_127 = device_127.objects.last()
    device_128 = device_128.objects.last()
    device_129 = device_129.objects.last()
    device_130 = device_130.objects.last()



    list_device = [
        device_101,
        device_102,
        device_103,
        device_104,
        device_105,
        device_106,
        device_108,
        device_109,
        device_110,
        device_111,
        device_112,
        device_113,
        device_114,
        device_115,
        device_116,
        device_124,
        device_125,
        device_126,
        device_127,
        device_128,
        device_129,
        device_130,
   
 

    serialzer_device = Deviceserializer(list_device, many=True)
    serializer_machine = machineserializer(list_machine, many=True)
    serializer_equipment = equipmentserializer(list_equipment, many=True)

    return Response(
        {
            "device": serialzer_device.data,
            "equipment": serialzer_equipment.data,
            "machine": serialzer_machine.data,
           
        }
    )
```

Comment: Can you add your models, views and serializers? I suspect you might be performing some unnecessary DB queries somewhere and you just have a lot more data in prod

Comment: i used silk debugger and it showed the overall time spent on queries are less than a second do you think this is still because of db? eventhough it worked ok in development? @IainShelvington

Comment: Without seeing your code or deployment it's impossible to say. Is prod consistently slow or are subsequent requests to the same URL faster?

Comment: "the speed is ok(255 ms) in development but it's sometimes fast (260 ms) and most of the time slow(30-40 s) in production" - well, the only evident difference is the environment it's running in, so I'd say it's the environment that's at fault.

Comment: i always send request with incognito tabs and it depends time by time . but it's slow most of the time,

Comment: i talked to the hosting provider and they said every thing is at high performance and the problem isn't from there idn't know what else could it be  :( @AKX

Comment: which servers you are used for hosting,  optimize it, check gzip is using, buffers...  Also add a test API url, which simply a simple json,  without hitting the database, and check it too take time, if yes it might be because of the configuration/hosting environment.  Also check the memory available in prod.  Make sue your API is paginated, also check web-server, application server access logs

Comment: If the hosting provider says "every thing is at high performance" they don't sound like they know what they're doing.

Comment: Anyway, um, that `device_*...` data model sounds like you really want `django-polymorphic` instead so each device type doesn't need its own query...